# Custom disabled style for Material UI's checkbox?

Tags: material-ui

Im building a design system which uses Material UI under the hood. I need to customise the design of a disabled checkbox.

In this code why is the `disabled` style setting the color to gold not being applied?

```
import CheckboxMUI from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

const Checkbox = ({ label, onChange, checked, disabled }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      '&$disabled': {
        color: 'gold',
      },
    },
  });
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControlLabel
        disabled={disabled}
        classes={{
          root: classes.root,
        }}
        control={
          <CheckboxMUI
            disabled={disabled}
            checked={checked}
            onChange={onChange}
            name="checkedA"
            color="primary"
            icon={
              <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon
                htmlColor={!disabled ? theme.palette.secondary.main : undefined}
              />
            }
          />
        }
        label={label}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    label: {
      '&.Mui-disabled': {
        color: theme.colors.disabledForeground,
      },
    },
  });

  <FormControlLabel
    disabled={disabled}
    classes={{
      root: classes.root,
      label: classes.label,
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Material UI's `<Checkbox>` allows you to provide custom elements for the `icon`, `checkedIcon` and `indeterminateIcon`. In your case, something along these lines would solve your problem:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  Checkbox as MUICheckbox,
  CheckboxProps,
  SvgIcon,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { ReactComponent as CheckboxChecked } from 'assets/svg/ui/CheckboxChecked.svg'
import { ReactComponent as CheckboxUnchecked } from 'assets/svg/ui/CheckboxUnchecked.svg'
import { ReactComponent as CheckboxIndeterminate } from 'assets/svg/ui/CheckboxIndeterminate.svg'
import { ReactComponent as CheckboxDisabled } from 'assets/svg/ui/CheckboxDisabled.svg'

export default function Checkbox(props: CheckboxProps) {
  return (
    <MUICheckbox
      checkedIcon={<SvgIcon component={CheckboxChecked} />}
      indeterminateIcon={<SvgIcon component={CheckboxIndeterminate} />}
      icon={
        <SvgIcon
          component={props.disabled ? CheckboxDisabled : CheckboxUnchecked}
        />
      }
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Which you would then use as follows (which is exactly how I solved this problem):

```js
<Checkbox
  disabled={someCondition}
/>
```